# Ajax: send value of textarea for one of multiple items of the same class

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

The following piece of Ajax code needs to send two pieces of data, an id (generated from a data-id attribute) and a tweet (generated from the value of a textarea).  When there is only one element to click on the page, it works perfectly.

However, I have listing pages calling the same code, with several elements of the same class on a page.  These pages fail to recognize the "tweet" variable being sent, and always fall back to the default. If I remove the default code in my script below, it sends no tweet.

Why wouldn't the following work with one of multiple textareas with a class of "tweet"?  Any ideas?

```
$(document).on("click",".send-tweet-button", function() {
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var userAPI = ' /api/tweetSideTaken.json';
  var tweet = $('textarea.tweet').val();
  if (tweet == '') {
    tweet = "My default text";
}
  var userInfo = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: userAPI,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      tweet: tweet,
      tid: $(this).attr('data-id')
    }

  }).success(function(json) {
    //success stuff
  };
    if (error !='') {
    /error stuff
 }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you query the class selector you need to iterate over each element to get each value.
Following would work for you

```
var tweet = '';
$('textarea.tweet').each(function(k,v){
    tweet += $(this).val();
});
if (tweet == '') {
    tweet = "My default text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

generally when you get data from those elements which need customer inputs and post it to server, the best practice is to set attribute 'name' to elements with different names. e.g.

```
<textarea class="tweet" name="tweet.title"></textarea>
<textarea class="tweet" name="tweet.content"></textarea>

var data = {};
$('textarea.tweet').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    data[$el.attr('name')] = $el.val();
});
```

if elements on one page apply a same class and you happen to query them by this class, $(selector).val() only returns the value of first element.